# Passing a variable defined in a sub onto a function VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I´m trying to use a sub to determine a dynamic range which serves as the input to a number of functions. The simplest version of what I´m trying to do looks like this

This approach gives me errors. Putting the subs and functions in different modules doesn´t help. What´s the mistake I´m making?

```
Global Info As Range

Sub InfoSetter()
    Worksheets("Example").Activate
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
    Set Info = Selection

End Sub

Function Test() As Variant

    Test = Info.Address

End Function
```

Comment: What errors do you have? Your code works ok for me.

Comment: Right, I see, it does work if I put them both in one module. But I´d like to put the sub in a separate module, so that I can run it from the worksheet to set the Info variable, while the functions should be in a second module. But when I put the second function in another module, I get a #Value error.

Comment: I guess you are getting a #Value error until first `InfoSetter()` call, considering that Info is empty. Add check to `Function Test()`, smth like `If TypeName(Info) <> "Range" Then InfoSetter`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below. This calls the sub from the function that sets the value of `info`. This means that your `info` will always be the current `UsedRange` when the function calculates. Also, using `.Activate` and `.Select` is generally considered bad practice. The below code does the same without using either.

```
Global Info As Range

Sub InfoSetter()
    Set Info = Worksheets("Example").UsedRange
End Sub

Function Test() As Variant
    Application.Volatile 'Added so function updates automatically when sheet calculates
    Call InfoSetter
    Test = Info.Address

End Function
```

Edit: Adding `Application.Volatile` at the beginning of your function will make it so this updates every time the worksheet calculates.

Comment: volatile functions can add unnecessary overhead, if you were going to force the range update, probably more appropriate on activating or deactivating the sheet that contains the range.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment from omegastripes, your error is likely to be because your range is empty. Given `Test` is a *variant* suggest you test for an empty range as below

```
Global Info As Range

Sub TryMe()
MsgBox Test
End Sub
```

*your code*

```
Sub InfoSetter()
    Set Info = Worksheets("Example").UsedRange
End Sub

Function Test() As Variant
If Info Is Nothing Then
    Test = "Ï'm empty"
Else
    Test = Info.Address
End If
End Function
```